# Como establecer en c# la ruta del directorio virtual para guardar archivos, esta carpeta se ubica en otra ruta dentro del mismo servidor en el IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

Solicito de su tiempo y conocimiento respecto a esta consulta, estoy grabando archivos .pdf e imágenes .jpg físicamente al servidor y guardo la ruta de las imágenes en tabla.

He conseguido realizar correctamente esto, bajo la siguiente línea:

```
    **private string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "evidencias/";**
```

En la línea previamente mencionada me crea una carpeta de evidencias\80\ **pero dentro de la carpeta del proyecto del sitio** (d:\trabajo\proyecto) esto al llamar a la acción del controlador que salvaguarda los datos y los archivos (.jpg y .pdf), **pero no es lo que busco**, pretendo conseguir se guarden estos archivos en un directorio virtual que definí en IIS dentro del subsitio pero que para el directorio virtual se aloja en otra ruta (d:\evidencias) diferente del subsitio (d:\trabajo\proyecto).

He intentado algunas formas que he visto por aquí y por allá pero no lo he logrado grabar al directorio virtual definido, me marca acceso denegado, la ruta no existe...., ya definí los permisos de escritura/lectura a la carpeta y no me funciono, **también definí directamente la ruta absoluta hacia el directorio directamente ** (d:\evidencias) y este me fue funcional pero solo en el equipo local, por lo que lleve a cabo la configuración igual en el servidor (hosting VPS mochahost) pero el funcionamiento en el hosting me indica que no encuentra el recurso al depurar en Mozilla en la consola.

Como debo hacer para llamar al directorio virtual alojado en otra carpeta, correctamente, se almacena en otra ruta, por que otro proyecto llamara a las imagenes y archivos que se guarden en evidencias tengo un modulo que se dedica a recolectar los archivos y otro modulo para otro tipo de usuario que los leera (les dejo imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano, trabajamos en MVC 5 / Bootstrap / EF / SP / VS 2019 / SQL.

Comment: intenta esto:  private string patch = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Evidencias\\");

Comment: Amigo Erick, System.Web.HttpContext no lo he logrado utilizar con MVC antes le usaba con el asp.net, pero ahora en MVC no me lo reconoce...

Comment: Intente de esta forma: 

private string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\evidencias\\");

Funciona bien, pero crea una nueva carpeta de evidencias dentro de d:\trabajo\proyecto y el directorio virtual queda sin los datos...